# assembly armv7 counting number of chars in a string

Tags: string, assembly, counter, armv7

This program is supposed to ask for a string input and count the number of chars
Any idea why I'm getting 0 chars for anything i input.

When I input hello for example,
the output was: "There are 0 characters in: "hello"

Here is my code:

```
.data

courseStr: .string "myName\t"

userInput: .string "\nThe string is:"   
    
countMessage: .string "There are %d charachters in:\"%s\".\n"



temp: .word 10

inputBuffer: .skip 15

inputValue: .string "%s"

.text

.global main


main:

    STMDB   SP!, {R4,LR} 

    LDR R0, =courseStr

    BL puts
    
    
    LDR R0, =userInput

    BL printf
    
    LDR R0, =inputValue
```

Getting input from user

```
    LDR R1, =inputBuffer
    BL  scanf
```

Getchar function

```
getLine:

    MOV R2,R0

    BL getchar
```

call count charactersloop function

```
    LDR R0,=inputBuffer
    BL  countCharactersLoop  // call the counter
```

charactersloop function
countCharactersLoop:    // counter

```
    LDRB    R0,[R1,R2]
    CMP     R0,#00        // if null then print   
    BEQ     countCharactersDone
    ADD     R1,R2, #01     // if not null add one
    B       countCharactersLoop // repeat
```

if char was null then we print the result
if not we continue to count

```
countCharactersDone:
// print "there are (numberOfChars) in the string inputed"
    LDR R2,=inputBuffer
    MOV R1,R0
    LDR R0, =countMessage
    BL printf
    LDMIA   SP!,{R4,LR}
    MOV     R0, R2
    BX      LR
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add an actual question.  Also, move the error description into the body of the question and chose a better title if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `CMP     R0,#00` compares the entire R0 to zero, not the byte register R0.

Another is that you invoke CountCharacters as:

```
LDR R0,=inputBuffer
BL  countCharactersLoop  // call the counter
```

But reference the passed string as:

LDRB    R0,[R1,R2]

and increment R1:

ADD     R1,R2, #01     // if not null add one

As a suggestion, write the function you desire in C, verify that it works, then compile it to assembly output (usually cc -S), follow the lead of the C compiler, then improve upon it once it works.